# React native background task action

Tags: javascript, react-native

Any idea how to run tasks after closing the app or clearing from recent apps in react native?
I have tried lot of background tasks libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with one of the background task library

```
react-native-background-task
```

You can implement it in the following way

```
import BackgroundTask from 'react-native-background-task'

BackgroundTask.define(() => {
  console.log('Hello from a background task')
  BackgroundTask.finish()
})
 
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    BackgroundTask.schedule()
  }
  
  render() {
    return <Text>Hello world</Text>
  }
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: but this will not run if app fully removed from background, Any idea by using react-native-background-actions api?